# Search users whose name contains Chinese characters

Tags: bug, search, languages, user-experience, user-search

## Goal

To search users whose user name contains Chinese characters.

[image: screenshot of user names with Chinese characters]

## Bug

In the above screenshot, three user names start with the simplified Chinese character '陈'.  I tried to search them with the input field.

[image: failed user search]

It worked well with Latin characters, but not the simplified Chinese character that I mentioned.

---

(Edit in response to @zcoop's question about SQL search string)

To search a Unicode string in SQL, one has to prepend the quoted string with `N`.

[image]

My corrected query: [https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1337166/display-name-containing-x?Characters=民主女神](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1337166/display-name-containing-x?Characters=%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%A5%B3%E7%A5%9E)

Comment: I don't think anything would stop you from running this search through SEDE, it should be possible there without the 3 char limit.

Comment: Then again... Maybe SEDE doesn't like non-Latin characters. [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1336874/display-name-containing-x?Characters=%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%A5%B3).

Comment: @zcoop98 I've appended a screenshot in response to your question, so that readers who don't have to time to look into the comments can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User search requires at least three characters before a search is executed.

If I enter `民主女` I get this result:

[image: shows searchbox with 3 chinese characters and one result]

and that is the expected result.

Comment: Bit of a localization issue, especially considering that a single Chinese character consists of one or more entire syllables.